# Can I use lstm/autoencoder to cluster multivariate time series?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder

I have a multivariate time series of driving scenarios which has X,Y positions, speed, orientation etc. of the vehicles. Each scenario A, B, C, D etc. are of different lengths with different delta ts for each scenario. I would like to use LSTM autoencoder to do dimensionality reduction so that I can later on use maybe clustering or other tasks on the representation. I came across that this the good process to go: data normalization using standard scaler--> Use sliding window approach to creater inputs as smaller sequences for the model (not sure if this highly beneficial)--> Padding and Masking --> Build and Train LSTM Autoencoder. I am new to ML but I do see super high losse. I am starting to doubt my process of sliding window or anything to do with pre-processing before I go forward with refining my model.

What do I expect to see from clusters?

I want to see homogenous scenario types like right-turn, left-turn, UTurn and standstill cluster groups:

What have I tried before?
-DTW only on the X,Y positions —> PCA —> K means Clustering: I am still unsure if this is good enough approach. I am not sure if DTW captures temporal dependencies between the trajectories so that it knows scenario types.

Why autoencoder?

I want to see if reducing dimensions (probably to 2/3 dimensions) of my multi variate time series using an LSTM autoencoder can help in clustering in unsupervised way.

This is my approach to dimensionality reduction using autoencoder and my modeling part below. I would like to if my approach to padding the variable length trajectories and then masking and then creating model is good start? I see the losses are too high:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Masking, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grouped = filtered_df.groupby('name')
trajectories = {name: group[['time', 'positionX', 'positionY', 'Orientation', 
'Speed']].dropna().to_numpy() for name, group in grouped}

# Extract and scale trajectory features (excluding time)
scaled_trajectories = []
for traj in trajectories.values():
   scaler = StandardScaler()
   scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(traj[:, 1:])  # Exclude the first column (time)
   scaled_trajectories.append(scaled_features)

# Define constants
special_value = -755.0
max_seq_len = max(len(t) for t in scaled_trajectories)
num_features = scaled_trajectories[0].shape[1]  # Number of features excluding time

# Pad the sequences
X_padded = pad_sequences(scaled_trajectories, maxlen=max_seq_len, padding='post', 
dtype='float32', value=special_value)

# Define the LSTM Autoencoder
latent_dim = 3 #or set to 2
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_seq_len, num_features))
masked_input = Masking(mask_value=special_value)(encoder_inputs)
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=False)(masked_input)
decoded = RepeatVector(max_seq_len)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(num_features, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(encoder_inputs, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
autoencoder.summary()

# Early stopping callback
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

# Fit the model with early stopping
history = autoencoder.fit(X_padded, X_padded, epochs=100, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.2, 
callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Plotting the training and validation loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Model Loss During Training')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Create a model for the encoder part
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoded)

# Dimensionality reduction
latent_representations = encoder_model.predict(X_padded)
# latent_representations now holds the compressed form of your trajectories
print("Shape of latent representations:", latent_representations.shape)
print(latent_representations)
```